# How to assign a value typed in edit box to a variable in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

in any other language that i used to program with you can assign a value to a variable using this code

```
String x;
Edit1->Text = x;
//or
x = Edit1->Text;
```

that's how its done in c++builder, how could i do so in MFC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you’ve defined the edit control.  Edit controls can be defined as containing a *CString* value or as an actual CEdit control.

So, if you’ve defined it as a CString, you can use something like…

```
std::string str;
str = m_edit;  // m_edit is edit field on dialog defined to use CString
```

Or, if using it as a control...

```
CString str2;
m_edit.GetWindowText(str2); //  m_edit is edit field defined as CEdit control.
str = str2;
```

Note:  You'll need to use the [UpdateData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9fb9hww(v=vs.120).aspx) function (or an equivalent) to transfer the string from the edit field to the local variable.

Comment: Every time i try to use this code i got red lines under my edit control name (IDC_EDIT1) ,, is that another name to the controls in mfc?

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the code you're trying.

Comment: im not trying to code something complicated, im new to mfc and just trying to view a message box after clicking on a button exists on the form beside a text box to enter the text to view in the message, how to do so?

Comment: If you see red lines under your control ID, make sure you included resource.h at the top of your code file.

Answer (score 1):

```
CYourClass::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
      CBaseClass::DoDataExchange(pDX);
      DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT1, m_strEdit);
}
```

`UpdateData(TRUE)` copies text from the dialog / view to the variable m_strEdit, `UpdateData(FALSE)` copies text from this variable to the dialog. Every time you call this function, `CYourClass::DoDataExchange` is called by the framework.

`CBaseClass` is the MFC class your class derives from (`CView`, `CWnd`, `CDialog` etc). `IDC_EDIT1` is the ID of the control as defined in resource.h, and used in your dialog resource file.
`m_strEdit` is type `CString`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code

```
CString x;
m_edit.GetWindowText(x);   // to Get editbox text

x = _T("Hello World");
m_edit.SetWindowText(x);   // to Set editbox text
```

Here `m_edit` is the variable of editbox.

Comment: Every time i try to use this code i got red lines under my edit control name (IDC_EDIT1) ,, is that another name to the controls in mfc?

Comment: @Kordy `IDC_EDIT1` is the id of your `editcontrol`. you can use that also to get and set text. use `GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1)->SetWindowText(x);`